# jQuery: Select radiobutton :nth-of-type(integer variable)

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button, attr, prop

I want to select the :nth-of-type radiobutton with jQuery using an integer variable as a parameter. But my jquery-code doesn't work.
Here is an example of my html:

```
<div class="col-md-12 question" id="q1">
<span class="q">1) What about shoelaces and long clothing?</span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" class="a"> I don’t need to care, the escalator is completely closed</span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" class="a"> <span class="cor">I tighten my shoelaces and keep clothing away</span></span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" class="a"> I shouldn’t wear shoes on an escalator</span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" class="a"> It’s a challenge to see if the escalator can catch my shoelaces</span><br><br>
<p class="info">You should check your laces and long loose clothes before you step on. Tie your laces before you get on and keep long clothes away from the steps and handrail to avoid that they get mechanically couth between steps or underneath the handrail.</p>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
// get value from url parameter (integer)
var q1 = urlParams.get('q1');

// check :nth radio button
$("#q1 .a:nth-of-type(" + q1 + ")").prop("checked", true);
```

This doesn't seem to work. I have also tried **.attr("checked", true)** and **.prop("checked", "checked")**. Both aren't working either. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to get ? Your question is unclear ?

Comment: whats the value that you get in q1? some integer value?

Comment: @maverickosama92 it's an integer indeed

Comment: is this https://jsfiddle.net/2tgvach5/ what you are looking for?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping the value behind my variable 'q1' is an integer. So I just want to select the :nth-of-type(integer value) of a radio button after the page is loaded.

Comment: @maverickosama92 This is indeed what I'm looking for. Why does :eq() work and :nth-of-type() doesn't?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes I've got the answer. Apparently I needed to use **:eq()** instead of :nth-of-type().

Comment: `:eq` is a deprecated function - Do not use that.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping then what should I use?

Comment: use it like that $("#q1 .a").eq(q1).prop("checked", true);

Comment: further read here: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: should i add a answer for you to mark it correct?

Comment: Yes! as @maverickosama92 suggested you need to use `$("#q1 .a").eq(q1).prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Indeed @maverickosama92 I've tried that and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Not necessarily but just to be curious: what would be a possible solution with :nth-of-type?

Comment: I know how to do that as well. But It’s a big complicated solution and more code. `.eq` Would be best in your scenario. Happy coding.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Ok no problem. Thank you!

Comment: Here it is => `$("#q1 span:nth-of-type("+q1+") input").prop("checked", true);` the `indexes` with `nth-of-type` means if you put q1 = 2 - it will select the first check box. So in a nutshell it means index range from 2 to 5 for your dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 question" id="q1">
<span class="q">1) What about shoelaces and long clothing?</span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" class="a"> I don’t need to care, the escalator is completely closed</span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" class="a"> <span class="cor">I tighten my shoelaces and keep clothing away</span></span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" class="a"> I shouldn’t wear shoes on an escalator</span><br>
<span class="parent"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" class="a"> It’s a challenge to see if the escalator can catch my shoelaces</span><br><br>
<p class="info">You should check your laces and long loose clothes before you step on. Tie your laces before you get on and keep long clothes away from the steps and handrail to avoid that they get mechanically couth between steps or underneath the handrail.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// get value from url parameter
var q1 = 1; //urlParams.get('q1');

// check :nth radio button
$("#q1 .a").eq(q1).prop("checked", true);
```

Working JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h8wfuz31/